# WF4 RC - ReceiveAndSendReply in a Flowchart

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, flowchart

I am using the VS2010 RC, and trying to put a "ReceiveAndSendReply" activity into a Flowchart. When I drag the activity out of the toolbox and drop it into the Flowchart, all I wind up with in the designer is an empty Sequence activity. Using Receive and Send activities separately seem to work fine.

Does WF4 support the ReceiveAndSendReply activity inside of a Flowchart activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double-click the sequence, I think you should find the missing activities inside.